# How to check is checkbox is checked angular2

Tags: angular

I want to check is checkbox is checked or unchecked in an if and else statement.

```
<md-checkbox id="mon" (change)="mon($event)" [checked]="true">Checked</md-checkbox>



mon(e){
    if(e.target.checked){
      console.log("This is checked")
    } else {
      console.log("unchecked");
    }
  }
```

I think I am doing it really wrong. I keep getting can't get checked of undefined. How is the way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can look at source code of material checkbox:

```
event.source = this;
event.checked = this.checked;

this._controlValueAccessorChangeFn(this.checked);
this.change.emit(event);
```

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-alpha.11/src/lib/checkbox/checkbox.ts#L288-L292

So you can do it like:

```
mon(e){
  if(e.checked){
    console.log("This is checked")
  } else {
    console.log("unchecked");
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh Yeah this angular2 thing  :)

Comment: can we use the same for <checkbox> ?

Comment: @TusharKukreti What is the problem with it? Did you try it yourself?

Comment: Yes i tried, and for `<input type="checkbox">` we need to use `e.target.checked`.

Comment: @TusharKukreti Yes, we should use `e.target.checked` for native checkbox

Answer (score 6):

declare a variable called it filter

```
filter: boolean= false;
```

then use ngModel in html part to access and assign its value.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="filter" (click)="filterData()">
```

it will call a function filterData() which you can use to do all your functionality

```
filter(){
  this.filter = !this.filter;// this will change value of it true and false 
}
```

for more checkbox you can use declare more variable like filter1: boolean

Comment: this is for the case when you want to do something when user select you checkbox or unselect your checkbox

Comment: This works for me. If checkbox is checked then filter variable is true other wise it is false. Thanks - @Amit Kumar