# "Deselect all checkboxes" not working with angular property binding

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, property-binding

I have used property binding in angular to deselect all checkboxes, but it is not working as expected. 
What i expected: After selecting one or more checkboxes when i click 'clear' button it should deselect all checkboxes.
here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DiPF9inrqT1uuXFPi94N?p=preview)

```
isSelected is the boolean variable which i have used to set the 'checked' attribute of checkbox.
```

**template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input [checked]="isSelected" type="checkbox">{{item}}
</div>
<button (click)="onClear()">Clear All</button>
```

**Component**

```
private items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  private isSelected = false;
  constructor() {
  }

  onClear(){
    this.isSelected = false;
  }
```

Comment: You are not changing the `checked` element attribute value like that, you are only changing the property `isSelected` value in your class.

Comment: to go on @onetwo12 you need to add `([checked])` the parenthesis make it a two way binding refer to similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41243563/5523033)

Comment: @onetwo12 isn't that 'checked' attribute dependent on 'isSelected' property of class?

Comment: The problem is that "isSelected" never changes (always is false). -You can probe that if equals isSelected=true at first - So, Angular don't refresh. Anyway you must have some that items=[{title:'a',selected:true},{title:'b',selected:true},...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ngModel` on your checkboxes and track the changes with `ngModelChange`. Also Set an auxiliary array to help you track the checked status. Here is a (simplified) example:

**HTML**

```
<input [ngModel]="isSelected[i]" (ngModelChange)="onChange(i)" type="checkbox">{{item}}
```

**Typescript**

```
 isSelected =  [];
 constructor() {
   this.onClear();
 }

 onChange(i){
    this.isSelected[i]=!this.isSelected[i]
  }
  onClear(){
    this.isSelected = [false, false, false, false];
  }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/wmb8vRwuErR3TdyiOnM3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input [(ngModel)]="item.checked" type="checkbox">{{item.label}}
</div>
<button (click)="onClear()">Clear All</button>
```

with the template:

```
private items = [ {'label':'a', 'checked': false },
  {'label':'b', 'checked': false},
  {'label':'c', 'checked': false},
  {'label':'d', 'checked': false}];

onClear(){
    for ( let cb of this.items ) {
      cb.checked = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should know [checked] not working and you should use [(ngModel)] for this thing and you should import FormModule from @angular/forms.

second, you should have multiple isSelected variable because if you use just one isSelected variable when you select one of them, all checkboxes will be select,
for that you can use array like this in **.ts** file,

```
items = [{name: 'a', isSelected:false}, 
         {name: 'b', isSelected:false},
         {name: 'c', isSelected:false},
         {name: 'd', isSelected:false}];
```

and in **HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected" type="checkbox">{{item.name}}
</div>
```