# Need to show/hide a dropdown after checking/unchecking a checkbox in angular 4

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a specific requirement in Angular4. 
I need to display a dropdown after selecting/checking a checkbox and if I uncheck the checkbox then dropdown will hide.
Below is the code of the checkbox.

```
    <div *ngIf="item.showOperationField">
        <p-checkbox
            value ="inflationaryImpactCheck"
            label="Save for Inflationary Impact"
            name = "calculationSaveInflation"
            [(ngModel)]="item.inflationaryImpact"
            pTooltip="Check the Inflationary Impact box to map this calculation to an index for Inflationary Pressure calculation.">
        </p-checkbox>
    </div>
```

After clicking/unclicking the checkbox

```
    <div *ngIf="item.showOperationField">
        <p-dropdown
            [style]="{'width':'200px'}"
            [options]="inflation"
            name = "calculationInflation"
            [(ngModel)]="item.selectedInflation">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
```

Please help me and let me know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You should check if checkbox is checked or not and depending on that setting the value of ngIf for your dropdown to true or false.
To check if checkbox is checked:
[check checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243308/how-to-check-is-checkbox-is-checked-angular2)

In the change event you should set the value for ngIf.
I hope you understood :).

Answer (score 0):

you can add click event on checkbox element, you check in your component if checked you set "show dropdown" to true:

```
    <p-checkbox
        value ="inflationaryImpactCheck"
        label="Save for Inflationary Impact"
        name = "calculationSaveInflation"
        [(ngModel)]="item.inflationaryImpact"
        (change)="showHideDropDown($event)" /* add this */
        pTooltip="Check the Inflationary Impact box to map this calculation to an index for Inflationary Pressure calculation.">
    </p-checkbox>
```

and in your component.ts

```
showHideDropDown(event){
 if(event.target.checked){
  this.showDropDown = true;
} else {
   this.showDropDown = false;
}
```

in your viw you show of hide based on this variable

```
<div *ngIf="item.showOperationField && showDropDown ">
    <p-dropdown
        [style]="{'width':'200px'}"
        [options]="inflation"
        name = "calculationInflation"
        [(ngModel)]="item.selectedInflation">
    </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. I added showDropDown: boolean; in component.ts as it is failing compilation due to non finding of showDropDown. Now compiling is ok. But in check/uncheck both the cases it goes to the else part. Could you please help me further?

Comment: try this please:  (change)="showHideDropDown($event)" instead of (click)

Comment: Tried. But no luck. This time nothing happens. Neither in if block or else block.

Comment: (click)="showHideDropDown($event)" and in your component use: event.checked and not event.target.checked

Comment: Ok I will check and let you know

Comment: @user3705879 No need to get complicated with an event, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're using PrimeNG.

Enable the binary option **`binary="true"`** in your `p-checkbox` tag.

From the [doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) :

> A single boolean value can be bound using the ngModel property as well by enabling the binary option.

Then you just have to display your `p-dropdown` if `item.inflationaryImpact` is true :

```
<div *ngIf="item.showOperationField">
  <p-checkbox binary="true" value="inflationaryImpactCheck" label="Save for Inflationary Impact" name="calculationSaveInflation" [(ngModel)]="item.inflationaryImpact" pTooltip="Check the Inflationary Impact box to map this calculation to an index for Inflationary Pressure calculation.">
  </p-checkbox>
</div>

<p-dropdown *ngIf="item.inflationaryImpact" [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
```

If `item.inflationaryImpact` is false, then the dropdown won't be displayed.

[Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/a4bGLouHtyS45ej8V0Me/)